# better way to write xsd elements reusable with in other complex elements?

Tags: java, xml, web-services, jaxb, xsd

I have the following xsd. Please suggest me how can I improve it.

```
<xsd:element name="getFirstTableRequest" type="tns:GetFirstTableRequest"/>
<xsd:element name="getSecondTableRequest" type="tns:GetSecondTableRequest"/>
<xsd:element name="getThirdTableRequest" type="tns:GetThirdTableRequest"/>
<xsd:element name="getFourthTableRequest" type="tns:GetFourthTableRequest"/>

<xsd:complexType name="Base" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="id" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" />
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="GetFirstTableRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="tns:Base">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="GetSecondTableRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="tns:Base">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="GetThirdTableRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="tns:Base">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>

  <xsd:complexType name="GetFourthTableRequest">
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="tns:Base">
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
  </xsd:complexType>
```

Is there any best way to improve above xsd? **I mean is there any scope to refactor above XSD** ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your extended types don't add any new attributes or elements.  You could do the following:

1. Eliminate all the sub types.
2. Remove `abstract="true"` from `Base`.
3. Then change each of the root elements to be `type="tns:Base"`.